# RoutePrefix with apiVersion pattern conflicts in Swagger documentation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, aspnet-api-versioning, swagger-net

I have two ApiControllers

```
[ApiVersion( "1" )]
[RoutePrefix( "v{version:apiVersion}/account" )]
public class LoginController1 : BaseController
```

and

```
[ApiVersion( "2" )]
[RoutePrefix( "v{version:apiVersion}/account" )]
public class LoginController2 : BaseController
```

Swagger doesn't show Login v2 untill I change `RoutePrefix` to `"v2/account"` instead of `{version:apiVersion}` 
or change same in V1 controller is also gives same effect.

It means one of them should be non pattern prefix 
I am using ASP.NET Api (not .NET Core) and [Swagger-Net](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net) version 8.3.23.1103.

Answer (score 1):

There are likely a couple of issues here.

The controller naming convention requires having the `Controller` suffix - exactly. This likely means that **LoginController1** and **LoginController2** will have problems, but **Login1Controller** and **Login2Controller** *should* work as expected.

Are you using the [API Versioning API Explorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning.ApiExplorer/) extensions? You'll want/need that package to support API version grouping in an Swagger/OpenAPI document generator.

Since you're versioning by URL segment, you probably want the corresponding API version automatically substituted in the URL path. This can be achieved with the configuration:

```cs
configuration.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true);
```

I hope that helps.